# Write a text file to Program Files (x86) via a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file which is going to write a text file and upload the file to an FTP area. The file needs to write to a folder which is in `Program Files (x86)`.

The script at the moment looks as follows:

```
@echo off
@echo A new version of Iconysis Agent Pro has been installed.> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\installed.txt"
@echo Installation date: >> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\installed.txt"
@echo Time: >> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\installed.txt"
```

However, it's not writing to the folder. It works when I set the directory to point to `\Documents`, but not with `Program Files (x86)`. Do I perhaps need to use a setting to give it administrative rights or something?

I''ve also tried replacing the directory path with `C:\Program Files (x86)...` but this didn't work either.

Comment: I would bet you are getting an error but you are not debugging your script correctly. Turn ECHO ON and execute your script from the cmd prompt.

Comment: Being likely that, `Program Files (x86)` is a protected system directory, have you tried running the script by right-clicking on it and choosing, `Run as administrator`?

Comment: @Squashman Ah, yeah, it says "Access is denied". How do I fix this?

Comment: @Compo I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Just a quick syntax note. When you are using ECHO OFF, you do not need to put an @ symbol in front of all of your commands.

Comment: @Squashman Oh, thanks, wasn't aware of that (This is my first batch file so still picking things up as I go along)

Comment: Code works just fine if you right click the batch file and run as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a UAC Prompt, you can use a Powershell command to rerun your script in elevated mode.

```
net file 1>nul 2>nul && goto :run || powershell -ex unrestricted -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath '%comspec%' -ArgumentList '/c %~fnx0 %*'"
goto :eof
:run
@echo A new version of Iconysis Agent Pro has been installed.> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\installed.txt"
@echo Installation date: >> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\installed.txt"
@echo Time: >> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\installed.txt"
```